Why is the output of the sampled signal in this question zero?


EDIT: I made an error in the previous image, now I corrected it.
Rephrasing my question:
Why is the output signal zero? The sampling only sampled the cos(14pit) frequency specturm only, it did not sample -cos(18pit). How did all they all cancel each other such that the output signal is zero?

"what does the output mean": it's the output. it has no meaning

"why is it zero here": because that's what you get when you calculate it. I'm not sure what your question is there! The answer to that is in the solution: it's simply 0.

I dont understand what output signal means? Is it the signal that got filtered out?

"The signal $x$ … is passed through the filter. Sketch the output signal": Clearly, the output of the filter is meant.

@MarcusMüller But why is it zero? The specturm has impulses at shown frequencies.

@MarcusMüller There were mistakes, I fixed them now and I rephrased my question.

The formula is literally right there. it's zero because if you look at the formula, the result is zero. You seem to have skipped the chapter where aliasing was introduced? Anyways, the $2\pi$-periodicity of the cosine should really be no news to you at this point.

Hints for the OP:

Forget about the spectrum, filtering through a narrowband filter and all that stuff, and just concentrate on $x(t)$, the continuous-time signal before it is sampled.  Write the signal as
$$x(t) = \cos(14\pi t) - \cos(18\pi t) = \cos(16\pi t - 2\pi t) - \cos(16\pi t + 2\pi t).\tag{1}$$
Use standard trigonometric identities for $\cos(A+B)$ and $\cos(A-B)$ to expand the two terms on the right side of $(1)$, and simplify the result.
Assuming you do all the above correctly, you should end up with $$x(t) =  2\sin(A)\sin(B).\tag{2}$$
Here, $A$ and $B$ are functions of $t$.
Now do the sampling, setting $$x[n] = x(t)\bigg|_{t=\frac{n}{16}} = x\left(\dfrac{n}{16}\right)$$ using the form $(2)$ for $x(t)$ instead of the form $(1)$ as is used in the solution to Problem 6.65.  If you have done everything correctly, you should be able to show that $x[n] = 0$ for all integers $n$ exactly as claimed in the last line of the solution.

